# unmet dependency ubuntu

Tags: dependencies

I'm trying to install `caffee` and `torch` on Ubuntu, but there are some unmet dependency problems. I have searched on the Internet for days but still cannot fix it. Can someone help? Thanks.

Below are the errors shown in terminal:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libopencv-dev : Depends: libopencv-objdetect-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg+1.5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libopencv-legacy-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libopencv-contrib-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libopencv-videostab-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libopencv-superres-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libopencv-ocl-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libcv-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libhighgui-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libcvaux-dev (= 2.4.9.1+dfsg-1.5ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
root@mingchuan-ThinkPad-T420:~/torch $ sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends libboost-all-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libboost-all-dev : Depends: libboost-date-time-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libboost-filesystem-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libboost-iostreams-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libboost-log-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libboost-system-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libboost-thread-dev but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libboost-wave-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
root@mingchuan-ThinkPad-T420:~/torch#
```

Comment: To quote a popular film: “We need to go deeper.” What's the output of, say, `apt-get install libboost-system-dev`?

Comment: @David Foerster

Comment: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-system-dev : Depends: libboost-system1.58-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Now do the same for `libboost-system1.58-dev`. We'll reach the root cause eventually. You can follow the thread yourself until you reach a package dependency issue that has a different reason than “but it is not going to be installed.”

Comment: Sorry for the mess, I just start learning it.

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:libboost-system1.58-dev: **Depends: libboost-system1.58.0 (= 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3)** but**1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 is to be installed**
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: It looks like some of the packages that you want/need to install rely on newer versions of the packages that are currently installed. You'll need to upgrade the packages on your system before you can proceed: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` then try again what you wanted to do originally. Please report back with the result, so I can either flag this question as a duplicate or think of something else.

Comment: **sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade**
[sudo] password for mingchuan: 
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt xenial-pgdg InRelease             
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
**0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.**

Comment: **sudo apt-get install libboost-system-dev**
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libboost-system-dev : Depends: libboost-system1.58-dev but it is not going to be installed
**E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.**

Comment: That's all very hard to read. Again, could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Comment: I found this helpful https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa to the problem